# python looping through list of tuples and creating list of dictionary

Tags: python

I am looping through this list of tuple and trying to make it a dictionary that contains two key-value pair where one being "word": "data" and "count":12

inside the loop when I print(my_dict) it correctly prints what I want however when final_list is printed it gives me a list of dictionary where all four entries are {word:"javascript", count:20}

```
 my_list = [("data", 12), ("sql", 13), ("python", 4), ("javascript", 20)]

    # make into [{word:"data", count:12},
    #            {word:"sql", count:13},
    #            {word:"python", count:4}...etc]

final_list = []
my_dict = {}

for s in my_list:

    my_dict["word"] = s[0]
    my_dict["count"] = s[1]
    # print(my_dict)
    final_list.append(my_dict)

print(final_list)
```

When I create my_dict inside the loop it works however I want to know why this is hapeninng.

Comment: You should consider named tuples for this rather than dictionaries. However, in your code you only ever make one dictionary and keep editing it.

Comment: You create dictionary once before loop started and each iteration you edit and add same dict into list. When you move assignment inside loop it creates new dict each iteration.

Comment: but each loop wouldn't it take current values and update it? why all four pairs are last pair

Comment: @makewhite, list contains references to same dict. So it contains result of last pair, because you set this datainto last iteration.

Comment: good further read [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) when you append the same object 4 times, it is all references to the same dict object. Each reference displays the changes made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to build a list of many dictionaries, your current code creates 1 dictionary and tosses it into the list a bunch of times.  You want each element in your list to be an INDEPENDENT DICTIONARY, they are not all the same.  The easiest fix is to declare your dictionary as a new dictionary in each passs of your for loop:

```
final_list = []
#my_dict = {} not here

for s in my_list:
    my_dict = {} # here instead!
    my_dict["word"] = s[0]
    my_dict["count"] = s[1]
    # print(my_dict)
    final_list.append(my_dict)

print(final_list)
```

This will make the code act as you expect it to

OUTPUT:

```
[{'word': 'data', 'count': 12}, {'word': 'sql', 'count': 13}, {'word': 'python', 'count': 4}, {'word': 'javascript', 'count': 20}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [("data", 12), ("sql", 13), ("python", 4), ("javascript", 20)]

    # make into [{word:"data", count:12},
    #            {word:"sql", count:13},
    #            {word:"python", count:4}...etc]

final_list = []
my_dict = {}

for s in my_list:

    my_dict["word"] = s[0]
    my_dict["count"] = s[1]
    # print(my_dict)
    final_list.append(my_dict.copy())

print(final_list)
```

Output

```
[{'count': 12, 'word': 'data'}, {'count': 13, 'word': 'sql'}, {'count': 4, 'word': 'python'}, {'count': 20, 'word': 'javascript'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're declaring `my_dict` *outside* the list. Every time you modify it, you're modifying the *same* dict - and you're putting that same dict into the list four times.

The solution is to declare *a new dict* every iteration of the loop. You'd do this by just putting `my_dict = {}` inside the loop:

```
final_list = []
for s in my_list:
    my_dict = {}
    my_dict["word"] = s[0]
    my_dict["count"] = s[1]
    # print(my_dict)
    final_list.append(my_dict)
```

You could also simplify the code by doing away with the helper variables entirely, and doing a list comprehension:

```
final_list = [{'word': s[0], 'count': s[1]} for s in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to append a new dictionary while iterating:

```
my_list = [("data", 12), ("sql", 13), ("python", 4), ("javascript", 20)]

result = []
for word, count in my_list:
    result.append({"word": word, "count": count})

print(result)
# [{'word': 'data', 'count': 12}, {'word': 'sql', 'count': 13}, {'word': 'python', 'count': 4}, {'word': 'javascript', 'count': 20}]
```

You could also use a list comprehension:

```
result = [{"word": word, "count": count} for word, count in my_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know why this is hapeninng.

As I've mentioned in comments, you assign dict object once before loop and use same object in each iteration. As a result you get list of references to same dict.

You can replace this code with simple list comprehension:

```
my_list = [("data", 12), ("sql", 13), ("python", 4), ("javascript", 20)]

final_list = [{"word": key, "count": value} for key, value in my_list]
```

Output:

```
[{'word': 'data', 'count': 12}, {'word': 'sql', 'count': 13}, {'word': 'python', 'count': 4}, {'word': 'javascript', 'count': 20}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this part...

```
for s in my_list:

my_dict["word"] = s[0]
my_dict["count"] = s[1]
```

every time you loop through you are changing the values in the dictionary. So, it makes sense that the dictionaries final value will be the final item in your list of tuples. I hope that makes sense.

Now looking at the last line of your loop...

```
for s in my_list:

    my_dict["word"] = s[0]
    my_dict["count"] = s[1]
    # print(my_dict)
    final_list.append(my_dict)
```

Every time you append the dictionary to the list you are not creating a new copy of the dictionary. You're creating a new reference to the dictionary. So all the dictionaries in the list point to the same space in memory that is being changed with every loop. To do what you want to do you have options...

Append a copy of the dictionary to the list. This creates a new space in memory with the values the dictionary had and appends it to the list. That way when you update my_dict the previous values are already stored elsewhere.

```
for s in my_list:

    my_dict["word"] = s[0]
    my_dict["count"] = s[1]
    # print(my_dict)
    final_list.append(my_dict.copy())
```

You could create a new dictionary in memory every time you loop through the values.

```
for s in my_list:
my_dict = {} # here instead!
my_dict["word"] = s[0]
my_dict["count"] = s[1]
# print(my_dict)
final_list.append(my_dict)
```

There's a couple other fancier ways, but hopefully this helps you wrap your head around this.